# Cassandra - Ubuntu Server Connect locally but no when connect remotely

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a problem when I want to connect to Cassandra remotely
I run it on ubuntu server and can connect to it through cassandra-cli

```
connect localhost/9160
```

But when I connect remotely I have an error

```
Connection Refused
```

Can some one help me what the problem?
Is it for firewall or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what interface is the `cassandra` process using:

```
# netstat -an | grep 9160.*LISTEN
```

If it only listens in the localhost interface, you need to [reconfigure `cassandra` to allow remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236898/apache-cassandra-remote-access).

Also, check if your firewall allows remote connections to that port:

```
# iptables -nvL
```

And add a rule if it doesn't.